# GitLab sidekiq log is empty

Tags: gitlab, sidekiq

I have just installed GitLab in Ubuntu through following the instructions here:
https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/

I am having some issues with email sending and plan to use the sidekiq log under the logs section.

I first realised that sidekiq.log does not exists, and so I created sidekiq.log using root, at "/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails". I then proceed to change the permissions and owners/grps to the same as other log files. Here's the updated permissions so far :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git    7935 Jun 24 16:02 application.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git      66 Jun 23 22:32 githost.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git 3306764 Jun 24 16:23 production.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 git git       2 Jun 24 14:35 sidekiq.log
```

I proceed to restart and reconfigure gitlab through the following commands :

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

However, I have realised that the sidekiq log is still blank. The other logs are ok. Anyone happens to know how to solve? Many thanks in advance :)

Image of sidekiq log section : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi0Dv.jpg

Comment: The default location for sidekiq logs is `/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/`. Try to create the `sidekiq.log` there

Comment: Thanks for your reply metaDiego, it still doesn't work, the gitlab's sidekiq log is still blank

Comment: Another stuff you can try: in my log files, the ones in `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/` are owned by the user `git` (exactly like the output you gave), but the one in `/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq` are owned by `root`. Try to change permission

Comment: I tried this too, but same results. I have added the picture in the main post.